# Slower performance for onClickListener when set in a separate method

Tags: android, performance, onclicklistener, android-lifecycle, fragmenttransaction

I have a fragment with many buttons.
Some buttons are unique, but many buttons do the same thing, where it sets an onClickListener for a fragment transaction.

The code looks like this:

```
    private Button mSetPresetBtn;
    private Button mGeneralBtn;
    private Button mSecurityBtn;
    [...]

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initViews();
        setOnClickListeners();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mSetPresetBtn = requireView().findViewById(R.id.btn_set_preset);
        mGeneralBtn = requireView().findViewById(R.id.btn_open_general);
        mSecurityBtn = requireView().findViewById(R.id.btn_open_security);
        [...]
    }

    private void setOnClickListeners() {
        mSetPresetBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogPresetSelection presetSelectionDialog = new DialogPresetSelection();
            presetSelectionDialog.show(Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()), "DialogPresetSelection");
        });

        mGeneralBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()).beginTransaction();
            FragmentSettingsGeneral fragment = new FragmentSettingsGeneral();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fl_settings_detail, fragment, "FragmentSettingsGeneral");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });

        mSecurityBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()).beginTransaction();
            FragmentSettingsSecurity fragment = new FragmentSettingsSecurity();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fl_settings_detail, fragment, "FragmentSettingsSecurity");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });

        [...]
    }
```

I have a lot of such buttons, and wanted to reduce redundant code.
So I changed the above methods where I created a list of Pairs for related Buttons and Fragments.

The new code looks like this:

```
    private Button mSetPresetBtn;
    private Button mGeneralBtn;
    private Button mSecurityBtn;
    [...]

    private List<Pair<Button, FragmentSettingsBase>> mBtnFragmentPairs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        initViews();
        createBtnFragmentPairs();
        setOnClickListeners();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mSetPresetBtn = requireView().findViewById(R.id.btn_set_preset);
        mGeneralBtn = requireView().findViewById(R.id.btn_open_general);
        mSecurityBtn = requireView().findViewById(R.id.btn_open_security);
        [...]
    }

    private void createBtnFragmentPairs() {
        mBtnFragmentPairs.add(new Pair<>(mGeneralBtn, new FragmentSettingsGeneral()));
        mBtnFragmentPairs.add(new Pair<>(mSecurityBtn, new FragmentSettingsSecurity()));
        [...]
    }

    private void setOnClickListeners() {
        mSetPresetBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogPresetSelection presetSelectionDialog = new DialogPresetSelection();
            presetSelectionDialog.show(Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()), "DialogPresetSelection");
        });

        [...]

        for (Pair<Button, FragmentSettingsBase> pair : mBtnFragmentPairs) {
            Button button = Objects.requireNonNull(pair.first);
            FragmentSettingsBase fragment = Objects.requireNonNull(pair.second);
            setOnClickListenerForFragmentTransaction(button, fragment);
        }
    }

    private void setOnClickListenerForFragmentTransaction(Button button, FragmentSettingsBase fragment) {
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()).beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fl_settings_detail, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });
    }
```

Functionality-wise, it seems to work fine. However, the performance for fragment transaction seems to have become much slower.
If onClickListeners are set at the onActivityCreated() part of the lifecycle, and each button is a member variable of the base fragment, then I cannot imagine why there would be a performance decline.

What is causing the performance decline?
How can I remove redundant code without losing performance?

Answer (score 0):

You Are creating instances of fragments

`private void createBtnFragmentPairs() { mBtnFragmentPairs.add(new Pair<>(mGeneralBtn, new FragmentSettingsGeneral())); mBtnFragmentPairs.add(new Pair<>(mSecurityBtn, new FragmentSettingsSecurity())); [...] }`

They are taking a lot of memory with no purpous.

I would suggest tu create and reuse listeners instead of Pair<Button,Fragment>.

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // do logic here and reuse it on views.
        }
    };

    button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    ......
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I want to reuse the same listener like you suggested, how would I pass different `FragmentSettingsBase` objects which is used in the `.replace()` method?

Comment: Just add FragmentSettingsBase initialization inside listener block and create it only when it is clicked.